# why can't perl6 just autovivify so that I don't have to use "my" all the time?

Tags: variables, declare, raku

In per5, I can just use a variable, such as $foo or @bar without using "my".

```
$foo=1; @bar=(1,2);
```

In perl6, why do I have to use "my" all the time? Otherwise compiler will say variable undeclared.Why can't perl6 just autovivify?

```
print "{my @a=1,2,3;}\n"; # have to use "my" to declare variable
print "{@a=1,2,3;}\n"; # this is error 'Variable '@a' is not declared'
```

I don't like the restriction of having to always use "my". This is too low level like C; very cumbersome.

Is there a way to turn on always autovivify?

Thanks.

Comment: The only reason it is that way by default is because that is the way it worked in previous versions. If you don't start your Perl 5 code with `use strict` and `use warnings` ( or other declarations that do that on your behalf ) you are writing terrible Perl 5 code. I recommend reading the book "Modern Perl" (provided by the author/publisher for free online).

Comment: This is not at all low level like C. Rather it is very high level. In very-very low level programming like assembly you can use any RAM address you want without declaring what you want to use it for first. If you happen to be forgetful this may cause you to accidentally use the same RAM address for two variables - causing a bug. `my` allows you to give a hint to the language saying: hey, this is where I declare my variable. If you use it before declaring the compiler can complain, if you declare it twice the compiler can complain. Then you know you've made a mistake.

Comment: *"The only reason it is that way by default is because that is the way it worked in previous versions"* But it *wasn't* that way before. By default every Perl 5 variable is a package variable. It is the default now because the Perl 5 way was wrong.

Comment: Perl 6 is superior to any other language I know. Ideas like this will break it. Default behaviour is chosen for very good reasons. Please don't.

Answer (score 10):

Not having explicit variable declarations is a terrible idea from the perspective of language design for various reasons. Arguably, explicitly declared block-scoped lexical variables are the way to go, and I find it crazy how many languages of the 'scripting' variety get this 'wrong' (there's a reason why `let` got added to Javascript...)

That said, Perl6 supports the `no strict` pragma which allows you to omit the declaration.

Answer (score 4):

```
no strict;
$foo=1; @bar=(1,2);
print "{@a=1,2,3;}\n";
# OUTPUT«1 2 3␤»
```

Perl 6 tries to help you with proper error messages. If you declare all variables it will provide you with a guess what variable you meant if you have a typo. Also there are new language features like constants and sigilless variables that are not possible to write down without declarators.

Comment: Great! Thanks for sharing your thoughts. I think I like the freedom of "no strict ".

Comment: @lisprogtor: Unfortunately that "freedom" includes the freedom to write bugs that the language doesn't report. For a very recent example, take a look at [*Write a Perl script that takes in a FASTA and reverses all the sequences*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38775912/) where the OP couldn't find a bug that was caused by them using both `$NUM_COL` and `$NUM_C0L`. The `my` keyword is one of the shortest because it is used so frequently, and any program that uses `no strict` that is more than a couple of lines long is a badly-written program.